# Efficient way to select rows with n to n relationship

Tags: .net, sql-server, performance, linq, entity-framework

I have the following relationship:

[image: Diagram]

I want to select all the rows from Ads where it has FeaturesOfAds related, so I'm doing this:

```
query = from ad in query
        join featureOfAd in db.FeaturesOfAds on ad.AdId equals featureOfAd.AdId
        where options.FeatureIds.Contains(featureOfAd.FeatureId)
        select ad;
```

`options.FeatureIds` is an array of int. It works but the problem is that the result returns a lot of duplicated rows and I need to do a `Distinct` call and I'm afraid it may get a poor performance under high load and with thousands of rows. So I would like to know if there is a better and efficient way to do this.

Comment: Is duplication is only of specific column?

Answer (score 0):

You should group you result by AdID in order to get distinct values.
Probably there won't be better solution then join with group. You can try Exists but I suspect it will be much more slow.

```
var result = (from a in Ads
join foa in FeatureOfAds on a.AdID equals foa.AdID
where FeatureIDs.Contains(foa.FeatureID)
group a by a.AdID into gr
select gr.Key).ToList();

var result = (from a in Ads
where a.FeatureOfAds.Any(c=>FeatureIDs.Contains(c.FeatureID))
select a.AdID).ToList();
```